# Can't get the target attributes of material-ui select react component

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm trying to get the id,name, and value from Select field element of Material-UI react component.

This is my container:

```
//some code is removed to keep things simple
class MyContainer extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    return(
        <MyComp onChange={this._onChange.bind(this)}  />
    );
  }

  _onChange(evt) {
    console.log(evt.target); 
    console.log(evt.target.id);  //blank
    console.log(evt.target.name); //undefined 
    console.log(evt.target.value); //html value of selected option!

  }

 }
 export default connect(select)(MyContainer);
```

in my presentational component:

```
  import React, {Component} from 'react';
  import Select from 'material-ui/SelectField';
  import MenuItem from 'material-ui/MenuItem';

  const someData = ["aaaa", "bbbb", "ccccc"];

  class MyComp extends Component {

    render() {
      const {onChange} = this.props;

      return (
        <form >
            <Select
                    value={this.props.test}
                    name={"test"}
                    id={"test"}
                    onChange={this.props.onChange}
                    hintText={"Select a fitch rating service"}>
              {
                someData.map((e) => {
                  return <MenuItem key={Math.random()}  value={e} primaryText={e}/>
                })
              }
            </Select>
        </form>
      );
    }
  }
```

Problem is that `_onChange(evt)` is giving this values:

```
  evt.id is blank
  evt.name is undefined
  evt.target.value is <div>whatever the selected value was</div>
```

It seems as though the passed argument to `_onChange(evt)` is not the `SELECT` but rather the option since when i print out `evt.target` it gives `<div>whatever the selected value was</div>`. anyone knows why? If i use a plain select field (not material-ui) then this works as expected (i.e. i can get the id,name, correct value of selected option). How do i get the target id, name..etc from onChange event of Material-UI Select component?

P.S i'm using the same `_onChange` method for TextField component of material-ui and it works there. I've also tried:

```
 _onChange = (event, index, value) => {
    console.log(event.target.id); //blank
    console.log(event.target.name); //undefined
    console.log(index); //correct index
    console.log(value); //correct value
  };
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Update 2

In response to your comments:

As per the [material-ui docs](http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/select-field), getting back the touchtap event on option element rather than the select element is expected. If you want the id and name of the element, I would suggest binding the variables to the callback:

The onchange method in the parent component:

```
_onChange(id, name, evt, key, payload) {

  console.log(id);  //id of select
  console.log(name); //name of name
  console.log(payload); //value of selected option
}
```

And when you attach it to the select component, you need to use [`bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)

```
   <Select
     value={this.props.test}
     name={"test"}
     id={"test"}
     onChange={this.props.onChange.bind(null,"id","name")}
     hintText={"Select a fitch rating service"}>
```

### Update

Here are the [react event docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/events.html#event-pooling). Under the event-pooling you will find reference to the use of `e.persists()` in the block quote. The explanation given in this [issue](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/2850) is that React pools the event object, so it get's reused when another event is fired.

---

React has a rather special event object. It wraps the native event in a synthetic event, which is what `event` points to in your `_onChange` method.
The problem is that this synthetic event object is recycled and reused for the next event, so it is garbage collected and set to null. I don't think this is well documented, but I'll search for a link and update this answer once I find it.

The solution is for the first line in your event handler to make a copy of the event, persist it, or get a reference to the native event:

### Make a copy of the event

```
_onChange = (event, index, value) => {
  e = _.cloneDeep(event); // Here I'm using the cloneDeep method provided by underscore / lodash . User whatever library you prefer. 
  console.log(e.target.id); 
  console.log(e.target.name); 
};
```

### Persist the event

```
_onChange = (event, index, value) => {
  event.persist() // This stops react from garbage collecting the event object. It may impact performance, but I doubt by much.
  console.log(event.target.id); 
  console.log(event.target.name); 
};
```

### Get a reference to the native event object

```
_onChange = (event, index, value) => {
  e = event.native; // This looks the same as a vanilla JS event
  console.log(e.target.id); 
  console.log(e.target.name); 
};
```

Comment: `event.native` gives undefined! also why is that for TextField component it works fine but not for Select component?

Comment: tried `event.nativeEvent`.  value of `event.nativeEvent` gives `MouseEvent {isTrusted: true, screenX: 1086, screenY: 640, clientX: 845, clientY: 543…}` which doesn't seem right! also `event.nativeEvent.target` gives `<div>selected option</div>`!~

Comment: somehow the target is the option that was selected and not the select component itself! i.e. event.nativeEvent.target spits out the html of was just clicked and i can't seem to find a way to get the actual target (select component) to get its id and name.

Comment: @JohnYounan, I've added an update regarding the specifics of how to get the id and name for the select element in the callback

Comment: just tried the code from second update and getting `"id" ,"name", empty string ` for each console.log in `_onChange(id, name, evt)` . any chance of a jsFiddle?

Comment: @JohnYounan I've updated the example to use the payload argument which is given in the material-ui docs. If you are still experiencing issues, you can make a jsFiddle of how far you got and I can take a look at fixing it up. I don't have the time to write a full one at the moment.

Comment: thanks @Caffeinated.tech . this seems to have worked `_onChange(id, name ,event, index, value) {
    console.log(id);
    console.log(name);
    console.log(value);
  };`

Answer (score 7):

I'd keep it simpler using `event.currentTarget` instead of `event.target`.
In your event handler, you can access the attribute of interest from the element that triggered the event by:

```
_onChange(evt) {
    console.log(evt.currentTarget.getAttribute("data-name");
    console.log(evt.currentTarget.getAttribute("data-value");
}
```

thus calling `.getAttribute` on the attribute name prepended by "data-"

Answer (score 4):

This is an answer for latest version of Material UI and React (2020):

You need to have the `name` property on your `<Select>` element. That name value should correspond to the field's name in your object.

This should work (`name` is set to the field you're trying to update):

```
 <Select
            labelId="demo-simple-select-outlined-label"
            id="demo-simple-select-outlined"
            name="taskType"
            value={props.job.taskType || ""}
            label="{props.label}"
            onChange={props.onTaskTypeChange}
          >
```

But this will not work (name is omitted). This will return `evt.target.name = undefined`:

```
 <Select
            labelId="demo-simple-select-outlined-label"
            id="demo-simple-select-outlined"
            value={props.job.taskType || ""}
            label="{props.label}"
            onChange={props.onTaskTypeChange}
          >
```