# Can't get attributes of material-ui SelectField in react

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm using [SelectField](http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/select-field) of material-ui for my react project.
I have tried many ways from this answer [Can't get the target attributes of material-ui select react component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39076399/cant-get-the-target-attributes-of-material-ui-select-react-component)
.

But they don't work.My `target.id` always equals `""`
How can I get the attributes (like `id`).

Here is my code:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        form: {
            resident_city: ''

        },
        ret_code: '',
        ret_msg: ''
    };
    this.handleList = this.handleList.bind(this);
}

handleList(event, index, value) {
    event.persist()
    const field = event.target.id;
    const form = this.state.form;
    form[field] = value;
    console.log(event, value)
    this.setState({
        form
    });
    console.log(form);
}


        <form>
            <SelectField
                style={style}
                id="city"
                value={this.state.form.resident_city}
                onChange={this.handleList}
                maxHeight={200}
            >
                {cities}
            </SelectField>
        </form>
```

---

**Update**

I tried to use `SelectField` without `form`,and I still can't get the `id` attributes.It is really confusing me.

Comment: Hey McGrady - at that stage you're accessing the synthetic touchTap event, not the component (or indeed a 'real' select element. To access that ID I would pass it into the function call - onChange={ this.handleList( 'city' ) }. This can then be accessed (without testing...) with handleList(id, event, index, value)

Comment: @rob_was_taken Thanks for your explaination,but I tried to use SelectField without a form,and I still can't get the id.It's confusing me.

Answer (score 0):

On the main component you define a prop name for select the form component let say your city component is called : cityForm

in your cityForm component

```
render() { 
return (
       <SelectField
                style={style}
                value={this.props.city}
                onChange={(e, index, value) => this.props.selectChange(e, index, value, this.props.cityName)}
                maxHeight={200}
            >
                {cities}
            </SelectField>
);
}
}
```

In your main comp you will have let say (code is cutted some part omitted)

```
handleSelectChange(e, index, value, name){
      this.setState({
      [name] : value,
    });
  }

render(){ 
 return (
  <cityForm cityName = "city1"  city={this.state.city1} selectChange={this.handleSelectChange}/>
  );
 }
}
```

Im building a dynamic form generator and it did the trick for me =).

Answer (score 0):

If a React class component is used, selected value can be accessed through its state object.

Alternatively, with help of Redux the Select's onChange method can dispatch an action and update the value in the main application state.

In cases when updating the main state isn't feasible and function component is chosen instead of a class component, getting the value from the component outside the function becomes cumbersome.

An easy way to fix it would be to add a hidden input referencing the same value as select uses. Consider the following piece of code. It uses Selector `field1` to update value through internal component state and binds it to the hidden field `theField`. The value can be further read an outside function during dispatch just like any other input field value in the form.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Button, FormControl, MenuItem, Select } from '@material-ui/core';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

const mapStateToProps = () => ({
});

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch, ownProps) => ({
  submitForm: (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log(event.target.theField.value);
    dispatch({
      type: 'UPDATE_THE_FIELD',
      theField: event.target.theField.value,
    });
  }
});

function Main(props) {
  const [field1, setField1] = useState("v1");

  return (
    <>
      <form onSubmit={(event) => { props.submitForm(event, props) }}>
        <FormControl>
          <Select
            value={field1}
            onChange={(event) => setField1(event.target.value)}
          >
            <MenuItem value="v1">V1</MenuItem>
            <MenuItem value="v2">V2</MenuItem>
          </Select>
        </FormControl>
        <Button type="submit">Update</Button>
        <input type="hidden" name="theField" value={field1} />
      </form>
    </>
  );
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Main);
```