# Material UI button : e.target.name is undefined

Tags: reactjs, events, material-ui

the following code returns an undefined value for [e.target.name] for a MUI button, whereas no issue for the TextField. Am I missing soemthing here ?

Thks and rgds

**apps.js**

```
            <TextField
                id="password"
                name="password"
                label="Mot de passe"
                type="password"
                placeholder="votre MDP"
                defaultValue=''
                margin="normal"
                onChange={handleOnChange}

            />
            <Button
                id="test"
                name="test"
                variant="outlined"
                color="primary"
                className={classes.button}
                style={{ margin: '2rem' }}
                onClick={handleOnClick}
            >
                Connect
            </Button>
```

**helpers.js**

```
export const handleOnChange = e => {

    console.log([e.target.name], e.target.value);
}

export const handleOnClick = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log([e.target.name], 'submit');
}
```

**in console**

```
["password"] "xx"
[undefined] "submit"
```

Comment: please consider the answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/61990515/9409425

Comment: please give a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/61990515/9409425 for a similar case

Answer (score 1):

From the docs of Material UI:

1- https://material-ui.com/api/button/

there is no expected property `name`

2- https://material-ui.com/api/text-field/#textfield-api

there is an expected property `name`

Buttons usually do not need a name attribute.

Can you please elaborate why you need it ?

Comment: wants to track which button has been click. Got a page with severl forms, but I want to have a single generic handleSubmitForm helper, used for each forms, and depending on the submitted form, trigger dfferent actions

Comment: you can use the following workaround: onClick={(e) => handleOnClick(e, 'test')} and in the func params should be (e, name)

Comment: I changed the design by adding the ID, name, at form level and adding the type submit in the button. fix issue

Answer (score -2):

What I change to make it worked and more generic

```
<form name="loginform" id="loginform" onSubmit={handleOnSubmit}  >
     <Button
       id="test"
       variant="outlined"
       color="primary"
       className={classes.button}
       style={{ margin: '2rem' }}
       type="submit"
       form="loginform"
     >
```